# using aggregate function once instead of multiple times inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is using a function inside of it and the function is expecting two parameters. 
My problem is  related to performance issue see below

```
 CASE 
 WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID), dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID))/60.0) > 8 THEN
      (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID), dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID))/60.0)
 Else 0
 END 
 Else
 0
 END)
 Else
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID), dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID))/60.0)-T.lunch
END
     as 'Total'
```

Now what I want to do is create a temporary table so I can use it to call the function instead of the way I am calling the function each time it gets to those lines with hundred of thousands of records to go through.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you actually need help with? How to [create a table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)? Or how to [insert data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) into it? Or maybe how to use that table in your query? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: What is the `FunctionName` function doing, if its selecting from tables that's probably the performance problem.

Comment: User-defined scalar functions are inherently inefficient in SQL Server (before 2012 anyway).  Post your dbo.FunctionName() function, and we can show you how to rewrite it as a much more efficient table-valued function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my function guys. i know how to write functions and this is working just fine my only problem is related to performence issue because this stored procedure takes about 30 sec to execute i want to be able to bring it down to maybe less than 10 seconds what i want is call my funtion other ways instead of calling it ten thousand times like i am doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse expressions inside a query like this:

```
select (case when NewValue > 8 then NewValue else 0 end) xyz
from T
cross apply (
 select NewValue = dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID)
) x
```

A cross-apply used in this particular way can be used to introduce new columns and reuse their value. This technique is good for reusing common expressions in the same query.

Normal batch-level variables can be declared like this:

```
DECLARE @NewValue int = dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID);
```

Comment: That method can only create new columns.  AFAIK, it cannot create new variables.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. You can declare a variable like this: DECLARE @NewValue int = dbo.FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID);

Comment: I know how to declare a variable and you cannot DECLARE them with CROSS APPLY, though your post says that you can.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I added clarification to my answer. I hope it is useful to the OP (he didn't provide feedback though).

Comment: It's still wrong.  There is no such thing as a "query-level" variable in SQL Server.  What you are describing is a derived column in a virtual table.  Calling it a variable, of any sort, is misleading and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is deterministic (or at least returns the same value regardless of clock time), you can set up a temporary table like:

```
select DatetimeField, DatetimeID, FunctionName(DatetimeField, DatetimeID) as val
into #tmp
from (select distinct DatetimeField, DatetimeID
      from table
     ) t
```

You can then rewrite the stored procedure to use this.

However, as your query is written, a deterministic function would simply return 0 for the datediff, since the two arguments are the same.

In the end, it seems that your performance problem may be related to the function being called.  The suggestion that you post the code is a good one.